# Reading .csv through DictReader

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I'm just trying to read a .csv using the first row as keys for the dictionary, with no success. My file has two lines (test), items being delimited by tabs.

```
subjectID   logID   logTimestamp    gameKey userID  writer  gameTime    gameCode    gameDesc
9991    1711774 6/13/14 E9E91B56    L11-13  general 358 1002    GAMESCRIBE_CREATED
```

Code :

```
def process_data(file_path):
    users = {}

    # Open the .csv file and creates a dict of actions
    with open(file_path, 'rb') as csvfile:
        spamreader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter='\t')
        print spam reader
        print spamreader.fieldnames 
        for row in spamreader:
            print row
```

I keep receiving this error:

```
    ['subjectID', 'logID', 'logTimestamp', 'gameKey', 'userID', 'writer', 'gameTime', 'gameCode', 'gameDesc']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "logEvents.py", line 41, in <module>
    process_data(logs_path)
  File "logEvents.py", line 11, in process_data
    for row in spamreader:
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/csv.py", line 108, in next
    row = self.reader.next()
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `for row in spamreader` outside the `with` block in your actual code:

```
with open(file_path, 'rb') as csvfile:
    spamreader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter='\t')
    print spamreader
for row in spamreader: # your code
     print row
```

Once you leave the `with` block the file is closed so trying to read from the file object fails.

Comment: The OP's code mixes spaces and tabs for indentation, and that is more likely to be the source of the problem-- it looks correctly indented to the OP, even though it isn't.