# How do I print a particular field from a CSV file in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, dynamic-programming, file-handling

```
import csv
with open('doc.csv','r') as f:
                file=csv.reader(f)
                for row in file:
                      if row==['NAME']:
                               print(row)
```

I wanted to print all the names from a csv file in python. I tried this using this method but I got a blank output. Can anyone help me out ?

Comment: Can you show your csv file ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reading .csv through DictReader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32572541/reading-csv-through-dictreader)

Comment: Instead of ``csv.reader`` try ``csv.DictReader``

Comment: Should I download a seperate module for that or is it inbuilt ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

row is just a list, if you want first column from row, try:

```
print(row[0])
```

if you want all row, just

```
print(row[:])
```

if you want cells number 2 and 4:

```
print(row[1],row[3])
```

if you really want to have a better control of csv try with read_csv() pandas method:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('AAPL.csv')
print(df['your_field_name_here'])
```